# Python restart syntax error

Tags: python

Alright so I was coding in repl.it, and in my restarting loop it goes like this

```
while True:
    answer = raw_input("Would you like to calculate again?(y/n)")
    if answer == 'y'
        continue
    else
        print ("Okay, Thank you for calculating with Greenhorn. Goodbye!")
```

I get an error message that tells me syntax in `if answer == 'y'` is incorrect. help?

Comment: please edit the question so we can read what is code and what is not.

Comment: You are missing a colon at the end of if and else statements.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed to add `colon(:)` at the end of `if` and `else` condition.

```
while True:
    answer = raw_input("Would you like to calculate again?(y/n)")
    if answer == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print ("Okay, Thank you for calculating with Greenhorn. Goodbye!")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have used `break` along with of-course `:` otherwise you may end up having never ending loop.

```
while True:
    answer = raw_input("Would you like to calculate again?(y/n)")
    if answer == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print("Okay, Thank you for calculating with Greenhorn. Goodbye!")
        break
```